# How many threads are spawned by this program (geturls9.hs)

Tags: multithreading, haskell, asynchronous

I'm reading Chapter 11 of [Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/pcph/). In that book, the following [program](https://github.com/simonmar/parconc-examples/blob/master/geturls9.hs) is used to get URL's concurrently:

```
main = do
  xs <- foldr conc (return []) (map getURL sites)
  print (map B.length xs)
 where
  conc ioa ioas = do
    (a,as) <- concurrently ioa ioas
    return (a:as)
```

Assume that the "get URL" jobs are `[g0, g1, g2]`. As far as I understand, `xs` will be bound to the following structure:

```
g0 `conc` (g1 `conc` (g2 `conc` (return [])))
```

Now, my question is how many threads will be created in this case. My guess is that 7 threads will be created (as opposed to the 4 that I would expect to use for this job):

```
 thread0: g0 `conc` (g1 `conc` (g2 `conc` (return [])))
   thread1: g0
   thread2: (g1 `conc` (g2 `conc` (return [])))
     thread3: g1
     thread4: (g2 `conc` (return []))
       thread5: g2
       thread6: return []
```

Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All guesses are wrong! There are in fact **six** threads spawned.

Let's bring out the sledgehammer—

```
import Control.Concurrent.Async
import Control.Concurrent (myThreadId)

import qualified Data.ByteString as B

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

sites = ["http://www.google.com",
         "http://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/Spade",
         "http://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/Shovel"]

getURL _ = return B.empty

annotate :: IO a -> IO a
annotate action = do
    tid <- myThreadId
    putStrLn $ "I'm a thread and my ID is: " ++ show tid
    action

-- <<main
main = do
  xs <- foldr conc (return []) (map getURL sites)
  print (map B.length xs)
 where
  conc ioa ioas = do
    (a,as) <- concurrently (annotate ioa) (annotate ioas)
    return (a:as)
-- >>
```

All of the actions passed to `concurrently` will be wrapped with `annotate`, which causes the thread to barf its `ThreadId` to stdout. Running this I get—

> ```
> +$ ./geturls9
> I'm a thread and my ID is: ThreadId 5
> I'm a thread and my ID is: ThreadId 6
> I'm a thread and my ID is: ThreadId 8
> I'm a thread and my ID is: ThreadId 9
> I'm a thread and my ID is: ThreadId 10
> I'm a thread and my ID is: ThreadId 7
> [0,0,0]
> ```

Your result for the same program will almost certainly differ in the particulars of ID number and ordering due to differences in GHC versions and racing, of course.

So, your intuition was good! Your analysis is only off by one because the entire expression `` g0 `conc` (g1 `conc` (g2 `conc` (return []))) `` isn't itself passed to `concurrently`, so your `thread0` is of course just the main thread, not one created by the async library.

Note that async provides [`mapConcurrently`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:mapConcurrently) for concurrently processing any `Traversable` so you don't have to build your own using `foldr`. Why this function isn't mentioned in *Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell*, I'm not sure. It was introduced in async-2.0.1.0, and the Haskell Platform version 2012.4.0.0 (which the introduction to *PCPH* mentions all the code was tested with) includes async-2.0.1.3. Probably a pedagogical reason, maybe the usual delays in publishing combined with the code having been developed against an older version of the platform/library, who knows. The same introduction mentions that “sample code will be updated as new versions of the platform are released.” If you feel strongly, submit an [erratum](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920026365)!

Comment: Actually, `mapConcurrently` is defined in terms of `concurrently`! So I would expect both versions to spawn the same number of threads.

Comment: You know what, I think you're right. I must have had a brain fart while I was looking at the `Concurrently` instances. For some reason I thought there was a fancy `wait___` combinator for more than two `Async`s, but I must have hallucinated it.

Comment: It took me a while to "unfold" the implementation of `mapConcurrently` using `traverse`, `<$>`, and `<*>`. It is a tricky implementation...